# Get Dropbox authorization code with manual "copy and paste"

Tags: java, dropbox

I'm working on a stateless REST API which I needed to integrate Dropbox Login mechanism as described here: https://www.dropbox.com/developers/core/start/java

The main problem I am facing is getting the authorization code. Simply put I can't use the `DbxWebAuth` approach due to the stateless nature of the app (no sessions). And is stuck in using:

```
DbxWebAuthNoRedirect webAuth = new DbxWebAuthNoRedirect(config, appInfo);
```

And athough the code is generated, there is no callback and use has to "copy and paste" the authorization code from the Dropbox page after allowing. Is there a way to automate this process?

My main goal is to get that authorization code and send it back to the API like `http://my-website.com/dropbox?authorization_code={authorization_code}`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Having the authorization code passed back to your app requires you use the OAuth 2 flow with a redirect URI. In the Dropbox Java Core SDK, this would require you to use `DbxWebAuth`. The `DbxWebAuth` implementation however requires that you supply a non-null `DbxSessionStore` as the `csrfTokenStore` parameter in the [constructor](https://dropbox.github.io/dropbox-sdk-java/api-docs/v1.8.x/com/dropbox/core/DbxWebAuth.html#DbxWebAuth(com.dropbox.core.DbxRequestConfig,%20com.dropbox.core.DbxAppInfo,%20java.lang.String,%20com.dropbox.core.DbxSessionStore)).

That is used to prevent [cross-site request forgery](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cross-site_request_forgery) attacks, per the Dropbox [/oauth2/authorize documentation](https://www.dropbox.com/developers/core/docs#oa2-authorize), which links to the relevant sections of the OAuth 2 spec for reference.

That said, the `state` parameter on /oauth2/authorize, where the CSRF token would be supplied, isn't required, so it would be technically possible to use the code flow with a redirect URI without supplying `state`. Suffice to say, this isn't recommended, and isn't supported in the Dropbox Java Core SDK. If you really needed to do this though, you could either implement it manually, use a different library that allows it, or modify the Dropbox Java Core SDK. Be aware that doing so may open your app up to cross-site request forgery attacks though.